# Ansible - Set-fact with loop variable?

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

To be honest, I am not exactly sure what I am trying to do is technically called but will try to explain the best I can.

## End_result:

I would like a list and/or JSON of data that looks similar to this:

```
"ansible_facts": {
        "fact_pcs_resource_status": [
            {
                "resource": "nfs-transfer01_18",
                "type": "(ocf::heartbeat:exportfs)",
                "state": "Started",
                "target": "testserver07.local.net"
            },
            {
                "resource": "nfs-transfer03_18",
                "type": "(ocf::heartbeat:exportfs)",
                "state": "Started",
                "target": "testserver07.local.net"
            },
            {
                "resource": "nfs-transfer01_19",
                "type": "(ocf::heartbeat:exportfs)",
                "state": "Started",
                "target": "testserver07.local.net"
            }
```

## Where I am stuck (explanation):

### Logic thought

```
- name: set_fact_pcs_status
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    fact_pcs_status: "{{ fact_pcs_status|default([]) + [ {'resource': item.0.name, 'type': item.1, 'state': item.2, 'target': item.3 } ] }}"
  with_together:
    - "{{ var_pcs_resources }}"
    - "{{ type }}"
    - "{{ state }}"
    - "{{ target }}"
  vars:
    regex_expression: "{{ var_pcs_resources.name }}\\s+(\\(.*\\)):\\s+(\\S*)\\s+(\\S*)\\s+(\\(.*\\)):\\s+(\\S*)\\s+(\\S*)"
    type: "{{ reg_command_pcs_status.stdout | regex_findall(regex_expression, '\\1') }}"
    state: "{{ reg_command_pcs_status.stdout | regex_findall(regex_expression, '\\2') }}"
    target: "{{ reg_command_pcs_status.stdout | regex_findall(regex_expression, '\\3') }}"
```

Now the above does not work and where I get lost.  I believe what I am actually need is a loop-in-loop to accomplish what I want with the 'loop_control' but not sure.

#### So in 'thought' code:

1. Pull the resource names out of the variable 'var_pcs_resources'
2. Use this as the loop index (as there should only be these resources
   configured on the PCS)
3. RegEx through the 'reg_command_pcs_status.stdout' to find the 'type,
   state, & target'
4. each iteration of the loop will change the 'regex_express' "{{
   var_pcs_resources.name }}" portion

I tried to break this up into different fact captures/creations but I cannot get past the point where I need to dynamically call in the variable into the regex_expression.

## Information:

### Ansible:

```
ansible 2.10.7
  config file = /app/ansible/ansible_linux_playbooks/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/etc/ansible/library/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.6.8 (default, Aug 24 2020, 17:57:11) [GCC 8.3.1 20191121 (Red Hat 8.3.1-5)]
```

### Raw_data:

PCS-status command output:

```
TASK [vcd_nfs_cluster : command_pcs_status] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /app/ansible/ansible_linux_playbooks/roles/vcd_nfs_cluster/tasks/verify_pcs_status.yml:3
Wednesday 07 April 2021  09:12:20 -0400 (0:00:01.065)       0:00:04.597 ******* 
ok: [testserver06.local.net] => {
    "changed": false,
    "cmd": [
        "pcs",
        "status"
    ],
    "delta": "0:00:00.273728",
    "end": "2021-04-07 09:12:22.729576",
    "rc": 0,
    "start": "2021-04-07 09:12:22.455848"
}

STDOUT:

Cluster name: nfsclst02
Stack: corosync
Current DC: testserver07.local.net (version 1.1.23-1.el7_9.1-9acf116022) - partition with quorum
Last updated: Wed Apr  7 09:12:22 2021
Last change: Wed Mar 31 10:33:35 2021 by root via cibadmin on testserver06.local.net

2 nodes configured
16 resource instances configured

Online: [ testserver06.local.net testserver07.local.net ]

Full list of resources:

 nfsclst02      (stonith:fence_vmware_soap):    Started testserver06.local.net
 Resource Group: nfsclst02grp01
     nfsclst02-lvm      (ocf::heartbeat:LVM):   Started testserver07.local.net
     lvm_transfer       (ocf::heartbeat:Filesystem):    Started testserver07.local.net
     nfs-daemon (ocf::heartbeat:nfsserver):     Started testserver07.local.net
     nfs-transfer01_18  (ocf::heartbeat:exportfs):      Started testserver07.local.net
     nfs-transfer03_18  (ocf::heartbeat:exportfs):      Started testserver07.local.net
     nfs-transfer01_19  (ocf::heartbeat:exportfs):      Started testserver07.local.net
     nfs-transfer03_19  (ocf::heartbeat:exportfs):      Started testserver07.local.net
     nfs-transfer01_20  (ocf::heartbeat:exportfs):      Started testserver07.local.net
     nfs-transfer03_20  (ocf::heartbeat:exportfs):      Started testserver07.local.net
     nfs-transfer01_21  (ocf::heartbeat:exportfs):      Started testserver07.local.net
     nfs-transfer03_21  (ocf::heartbeat:exportfs):      Started testserver07.local.net
     nfs-transfer01_22  (ocf::heartbeat:exportfs):      Started testserver07.local.net
     nfs-transfer03_22  (ocf::heartbeat:exportfs):      Started testserver07.local.net
     nfs_vip    (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):       Started testserver07.local.net
     nfs-notify (ocf::heartbeat:nfsnotify):     Started testserver07.local.net

Daemon Status:
  corosync: active/enabled
  pacemaker: active/enabled
  pcsd: active/enabled
```

### Resource variable:

```
var_pcs_resources:

  - name: 'nfsclst02-lvm'
    type: 'ocf:heartbeat:LVM'
    opts: >-
      volgrpname=vg02_lvm_transfer
      exclusive=true
      --group nfsclst02grp01

  - name: 'lvm_transfer'
    type: 'ocf:heartbeat:Filesystem'
    opts: >-
      device=/dev/vg02_lvm_transfer/lvm_transfer
      directory=/storage/lvm_transfer
      fstype=ext4
      --group nfsclst02grp01

  - name: 'nfs-daemon'
    type: 'ocf:heartbeat:nfsserver'
    opts: >-
      nfs_shared_infodir=/storage/lvm_transfer/nfsinfo
      nfs_no_notify=true
      --group nfsclst02grp01

  - name: 'nfs-transfer01_18'
    type: 'ocf:heartbeat:exportfs'
    opts: >-
      --force
      clientspec={{ var_vcdc01_ip }}/32
      options=rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash
      directory=/storage/lvm_transfer/exports/transfer01
      fsid=0
      --group nfsclst02grp01

  - name: 'nfs-transfer03_18'
    type: 'ocf:heartbeat:exportfs'
    opts: >-
      --force
      clientspec={{ var_vcdc01_ip }}/32
      options=rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash
      directory=/storage/lvm_transfer/exports/transfer03
      fsid=1
      --group nfsclst02grp01

  - name: 'nfs-transfer01_19'
    type: 'ocf:heartbeat:exportfs'
    opts: >-
      --force
      clientspec={{ var_vcdc02_ip }}/32
      options=rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash
      directory=/storage/lvm_transfer/exports/transfer01
      fsid=0
      --group nfsclst02grp01

  - name: 'nfs-transfer03_19'
    type: 'ocf:heartbeat:exportfs'
    opts: >-
      --force
      clientspec={{ var_vcdc02_ip }}/32
      options=rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash
      directory=/storage/lvm_transfer/exports/transfer03
      fsid=1
      --group nfsclst02grp01

  - name: 'nfs-transfer01_20'
    type: 'ocf:heartbeat:exportfs'
    opts: >-
      --force
      clientspec={{ var_vcdc03_ip }}/32
      options=rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash
      directory=/storage/lvm_transfer/exports/transfer01
      fsid=0
      --group nfsclst02grp01

  - name: 'nfs-transfer03_20'
    type: 'ocf:heartbeat:exportfs'
    opts: >-
      --force
      clientspec={{ var_vcdc03_ip }}/32
      options=rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash
      directory=/storage/lvm_transfer/exports/transfer03
      fsid=1
      --group nfsclst02grp01

  - name: 'nfs-transfer01_21'
    type: 'ocf:heartbeat:exportfs'
    opts: >-
      --force
      clientspec={{ var_vcdc04_ip }}/32
      options=rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash
      directory=/storage/lvm_transfer/exports/transfer01
      fsid=0
      --group nfsclst02grp01

  - name: 'nfs-transfer03_21'
    type: 'ocf:heartbeat:exportfs'
    opts: >-
      --force
      clientspec={{ var_vcdc04_ip }}/32
      options=rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash
      directory=/storage/lvm_transfer/exports/transfer03
      fsid=1
      --group nfsclst02grp01

  - name: 'nfs-transfer01_22'
    type: 'ocf:heartbeat:exportfs'
    opts: >-
      --force
      clientspec={{ var_vcdc05_ip }}/32
      options=rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash
      directory=/storage/lvm_transfer/exports/transfer01
      fsid=0
      --group nfsclst02grp01

  - name: 'nfs-transfer03_22'
    type: 'ocf:heartbeat:exportfs'
    opts: >-
      --force
      clientspec={{ var_vcdc05_ip }}/32
      options=rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash
      directory=/storage/lvm_transfer/exports/transfer03
      fsid=1
      --group nfsclst02grp01

  - name: 'nfs_vip'
    type: 'ocf:heartbeat:IPaddr2'
    opts: "ip={{ var_nfsclst02_vip }} cidr_netmask=24 --group nfsclst02grp01"

  - name: 'nfs-notify'
    type: 'ocf:heartbeat:nfsnotify'
    opts: "source_host={{ var_nfsclst02_vip }} --group nfsclst02grp01"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be something broken:

- in your regular expression
- in the complexity you are bringing in your loop

---

With `regex_findall` you can get a list of all the matches, so you don't need to have multiple `regex_findall`.

The resulting list would actually be a list of list contains all the matches, then for each matches line, the fragments that you are capturing with the capturing groups of your regular expression.

So, given:

```yaml
regex_expression: "{{ item.name }}\\s+(\\S+):\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)"
matches: "{{ reg_command_pcs_status.stdout | regex_findall(regex_expression) }}"
```

On the string

```
nfsclst02-lvm      (ocf::heartbeat:LVM):   Started testserver07.local.net
```

- `matches.0.0` would be `(ocf::heartbeat:LVM)`, so, your `type`
- `matches.0.1` would be `Started`, so, your `state`
- `matches.0.2` would be `testserver07.local.net`, so, your `target`

Now, because you do only have one match per search, you could simplify this and [`flatten`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#managing-list-variables) the list of list, ending in

```yaml
regex_expression: "{{ item.name }}\\s+(\\S+):\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)"
matches: "{{ reg_command_pcs_status.stdout | regex_findall(regex_expression) | flatten }}"
```

Which would simplify the matches to:

- `matches.0` would be `(ocf::heartbeat:LVM)`, so, your `type`
- `matches.1` would be `Started`, so, your `state`
- `matches.2` would be `testserver07.local.net`, so, your `target`

So your task end up being:

```yaml
- name: set_fact_pcs_status
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    fact_pcs_status: "{{ fact_pcs_status|default([]) + [ {'resource': item.name, 'type': matches.0, 'state': matches.1, 'target': matches.2 } ] }}"
  loop: "{{ var_pcs_resources }}"
  vars:
    regex_expression: "{{ item.name }}\\s+(\\S+):\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)"
    matches: "{{ reg_command_pcs_status.stdout | regex_findall(regex_expression) | flatten }}"
```

---

Given the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        fact_pcs_status: "{{ fact_pcs_status|default([]) + [ {'resource': item.name, 'type': matches.0, 'state': matches.1, 'target': matches.2 } ] }}"
      loop: "{{ var_pcs_resources }}"
      vars:
        regex_expression: "{{ item.name }}\\s+(\\S+):\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)"
        matches: "{{ reg_command_pcs_status.stdout | regex_findall(regex_expression) | flatten }}"
        var_vcdc01_ip: foo
        var_nfsclst02_vip: bar
        var_vcdc02_ip: bar_ip
        var_vcdc03_ip: baz
        var_vcdc04_ip: qux
        var_vcdc05_ip: quux
        reg_command_pcs_status:
          stdout: >-
            Cluster name: nfsclst02
            Stack: corosync
            Current DC: testserver07.local.net (version 1.1.23-1.el7_9.1-9acf116022) - partition with quorum
            Last updated: Wed Apr  7 09:12:22 2021
            Last change: Wed Mar 31 10:33:35 2021 by root via cibadmin on testserver06.local.net

            2 nodes configured
            16 resource instances configured

            Online: [ testserver06.local.net testserver07.local.net ]

            Full list of resources:

            nfsclst02      (stonith:fence_vmware_soap):    Started testserver06.local.net
            Resource Group: nfsclst02grp01
                nfsclst02-lvm      (ocf::heartbeat:LVM):   Started testserver07.local.net
                lvm_transfer       (ocf::heartbeat:Filesystem):    Started testserver07.local.net
                nfs-daemon (ocf::heartbeat:nfsserver):     Started testserver07.local.net
                nfs-transfer01_18  (ocf::heartbeat:exportfs):      Started testserver07.local.net
                nfs-transfer03_18  (ocf::heartbeat:exportfs):      Started testserver07.local.net
                nfs-transfer01_19  (ocf::heartbeat:exportfs):      Started testserver07.local.net
                nfs-transfer03_19  (ocf::heartbeat:exportfs):      Started testserver07.local.net
                nfs-transfer01_20  (ocf::heartbeat:exportfs):      Started testserver07.local.net
                nfs-transfer03_20  (ocf::heartbeat:exportfs):      Started testserver07.local.net
                nfs-transfer01_21  (ocf::heartbeat:exportfs):      Started testserver07.local.net
                nfs-transfer03_21  (ocf::heartbeat:exportfs):      Started testserver07.local.net
                nfs-transfer01_22  (ocf::heartbeat:exportfs):      Started testserver07.local.net
                nfs-transfer03_22  (ocf::heartbeat:exportfs):      Started testserver07.local.net
                nfs_vip    (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):       Started testserver07.local.net
                nfs-notify (ocf::heartbeat:nfsnotify):     Started testserver07.local.net

            Daemon Status:
              corosync: active/enabled
              pacemaker: active/enabled
              pcsd: active/enabled
        var_pcs_resources:
          - name: 'nfsclst02-lvm'
            type: 'ocf:heartbeat:LVM'
            opts: >-
              volgrpname=vg02_lvm_transfer
              exclusive=true
              --group nfsclst02grp01
          - name: 'lvm_transfer'
            type: 'ocf:heartbeat:Filesystem'
            opts: >-
              device=/dev/vg02_lvm_transfer/lvm_transfer
              directory=/storage/lvm_transfer
              fstype=ext4
              --group nfsclst02grp01
          - name: 'nfs-daemon'
            type: 'ocf:heartbeat:nfsserver'
            opts: >-
              nfs_shared_infodir=/storage/lvm_transfer/nfsinfo
              nfs_no_notify=true
              --group nfsclst02grp01
          - name: 'nfs-transfer01_18'
            type: 'ocf:heartbeat:exportfs'
            opts: >-
              --force
              clientspec={{ var_vcdc01_ip }}/32
              options=rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash
              directory=/storage/lvm_transfer/exports/transfer01
              fsid=0
              --group nfsclst02grp01
          - name: 'nfs-transfer03_18'
            type: 'ocf:heartbeat:exportfs'
            opts: >-
              --force
              clientspec={{ var_vcdc01_ip }}/32
              options=rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash
              directory=/storage/lvm_transfer/exports/transfer03
              fsid=1
              --group nfsclst02grp01
          - name: 'nfs-transfer01_19'
            type: 'ocf:heartbeat:exportfs'
            opts: >-
              --force
              clientspec={{ var_vcdc02_ip }}/32
              options=rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash
              directory=/storage/lvm_transfer/exports/transfer01
              fsid=0
              --group nfsclst02grp01
          - name: 'nfs-transfer03_19'
            type: 'ocf:heartbeat:exportfs'
            opts: >-
              --force
              clientspec={{ var_vcdc02_ip }}/32
              options=rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash
              directory=/storage/lvm_transfer/exports/transfer03
              fsid=1
              --group nfsclst02grp01
          - name: 'nfs-transfer01_20'
            type: 'ocf:heartbeat:exportfs'
            opts: >-
              --force
              clientspec={{ var_vcdc03_ip }}/32
              options=rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash
              directory=/storage/lvm_transfer/exports/transfer01
              fsid=0
              --group nfsclst02grp01
          - name: 'nfs-transfer03_20'
            type: 'ocf:heartbeat:exportfs'
            opts: >-
              --force
              clientspec={{ var_vcdc03_ip }}/32
              options=rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash
              directory=/storage/lvm_transfer/exports/transfer03
              fsid=1
              --group nfsclst02grp01
          - name: 'nfs-transfer01_21'
            type: 'ocf:heartbeat:exportfs'
            opts: >-
              --force
              clientspec={{ var_vcdc04_ip }}/32
              options=rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash
              directory=/storage/lvm_transfer/exports/transfer01
              fsid=0
              --group nfsclst02grp01
          - name: 'nfs-transfer03_21'
            type: 'ocf:heartbeat:exportfs'
            opts: >-
              --force
              clientspec={{ var_vcdc04_ip }}/32
              options=rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash
              directory=/storage/lvm_transfer/exports/transfer03
              fsid=1
              --group nfsclst02grp01
          - name: 'nfs-transfer01_22'
            type: 'ocf:heartbeat:exportfs'
            opts: >-
              --force
              clientspec={{ var_vcdc05_ip }}/32
              options=rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash
              directory=/storage/lvm_transfer/exports/transfer01
              fsid=0
              --group nfsclst02grp01
          - name: 'nfs-transfer03_22'
            type: 'ocf:heartbeat:exportfs'
            opts: >-
              --force
              clientspec={{ var_vcdc05_ip }}/32
              options=rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash
              directory=/storage/lvm_transfer/exports/transfer03
              fsid=1
              --group nfsclst02grp01
          - name: 'nfs_vip'
            type: 'ocf:heartbeat:IPaddr2'
            opts: "ip={{ var_nfsclst02_vip }} cidr_netmask=24 --group nfsclst02grp01"
          - name: 'nfs-notify'
            type: 'ocf:heartbeat:nfsnotify'
            opts: "source_host={{ var_nfsclst02_vip }} --group nfsclst02grp01"
          

    - ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "{{ fact_pcs_status }}"
```

This yields the recap:

```
PLAY [all] *******************************************************************************************************

TASK [ansible.builtin.set_fact] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'nfsclst02-lvm', 'type': 'ocf:heartbeat:LVM', 'opts': 'volgrpname=vg02_lvm_transfer exclusive=true --group nfsclst02grp01'})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'lvm_transfer', 'type': 'ocf:heartbeat:Filesystem', 'opts': 'device=/dev/vg02_lvm_transfer/lvm_transfer directory=/storage/lvm_transfer fstype=ext4 --group nfsclst02grp01'})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'nfs-daemon', 'type': 'ocf:heartbeat:nfsserver', 'opts': 'nfs_shared_infodir=/storage/lvm_transfer/nfsinfo nfs_no_notify=true --group nfsclst02grp01'})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'nfs-transfer01_18', 'type': 'ocf:heartbeat:exportfs', 'opts': '--force clientspec=foo/32 options=rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash directory=/storage/lvm_transfer/exports/transfer01 fsid=0 --group nfsclst02grp01'})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'nfs-transfer03_18', 'type': 'ocf:heartbeat:exportfs', 'opts': '--force clientspec=foo/32 options=rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash directory=/storage/lvm_transfer/exports/transfer03 fsid=1 --group nfsclst02grp01'})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'nfs-transfer01_19', 'type': 'ocf:heartbeat:exportfs', 'opts': '--force clientspec=bar_ip/32 options=rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash directory=/storage/lvm_transfer/exports/transfer01 fsid=0 --group nfsclst02grp01'})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'nfs-transfer03_19', 'type': 'ocf:heartbeat:exportfs', 'opts': '--force clientspec=bar_ip/32 options=rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash directory=/storage/lvm_transfer/exports/transfer03 fsid=1 --group nfsclst02grp01'})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'nfs-transfer01_20', 'type': 'ocf:heartbeat:exportfs', 'opts': '--force clientspec=baz/32 options=rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash directory=/storage/lvm_transfer/exports/transfer01 fsid=0 --group nfsclst02grp01'})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'nfs-transfer03_20', 'type': 'ocf:heartbeat:exportfs', 'opts': '--force clientspec=baz/32 options=rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash directory=/storage/lvm_transfer/exports/transfer03 fsid=1 --group nfsclst02grp01'})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'nfs-transfer01_21', 'type': 'ocf:heartbeat:exportfs', 'opts': '--force clientspec=qux/32 options=rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash directory=/storage/lvm_transfer/exports/transfer01 fsid=0 --group nfsclst02grp01'})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'nfs-transfer03_21', 'type': 'ocf:heartbeat:exportfs', 'opts': '--force clientspec=qux/32 options=rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash directory=/storage/lvm_transfer/exports/transfer03 fsid=1 --group nfsclst02grp01'})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'nfs-transfer01_22', 'type': 'ocf:heartbeat:exportfs', 'opts': '--force clientspec=quux/32 options=rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash directory=/storage/lvm_transfer/exports/transfer01 fsid=0 --group nfsclst02grp01'})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'nfs-transfer03_22', 'type': 'ocf:heartbeat:exportfs', 'opts': '--force clientspec=quux/32 options=rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash directory=/storage/lvm_transfer/exports/transfer03 fsid=1 --group nfsclst02grp01'})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'nfs_vip', 'type': 'ocf:heartbeat:IPaddr2', 'opts': 'ip=bar cidr_netmask=24 --group nfsclst02grp01'})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'nfs-notify', 'type': 'ocf:heartbeat:nfsnotify', 'opts': 'source_host=bar --group nfsclst02grp01'})

TASK [ansible.builtin.debug] *************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg:
  - resource: nfsclst02-lvm
    state: Started
    target: testserver07.local.net
    type: (ocf::heartbeat:LVM)
  - resource: lvm_transfer
    state: Started
    target: testserver07.local.net
    type: (ocf::heartbeat:Filesystem)
  - resource: nfs-daemon
    state: Started
    target: testserver07.local.net
    type: (ocf::heartbeat:nfsserver)
  - resource: nfs-transfer01_18
    state: Started
    target: testserver07.local.net
    type: (ocf::heartbeat:exportfs)
  - resource: nfs-transfer03_18
    state: Started
    target: testserver07.local.net
    type: (ocf::heartbeat:exportfs)
  - resource: nfs-transfer01_19
    state: Started
    target: testserver07.local.net
    type: (ocf::heartbeat:exportfs)
  - resource: nfs-transfer03_19
    state: Started
    target: testserver07.local.net
    type: (ocf::heartbeat:exportfs)
  - resource: nfs-transfer01_20
    state: Started
    target: testserver07.local.net
    type: (ocf::heartbeat:exportfs)
  - resource: nfs-transfer03_20
    state: Started
    target: testserver07.local.net
    type: (ocf::heartbeat:exportfs)
  - resource: nfs-transfer01_21
    state: Started
    target: testserver07.local.net
    type: (ocf::heartbeat:exportfs)
  - resource: nfs-transfer03_21
    state: Started
    target: testserver07.local.net
    type: (ocf::heartbeat:exportfs)
  - resource: nfs-transfer01_22
    state: Started
    target: testserver07.local.net
    type: (ocf::heartbeat:exportfs)
  - resource: nfs-transfer03_22
    state: Started
    target: testserver07.local.net
    type: (ocf::heartbeat:exportfs)
  - resource: nfs_vip
    state: Started
    target: testserver07.local.net
    type: (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2)
  - resource: nfs-notify
    state: Started
    target: testserver07.local.net
    type: (ocf::heartbeat:nfsnotify)

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: @B.enoit.Be
That clarified the issue very well and gave me the basis.
I ended up with a slightly different setup but still need this for another issue.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a slightly different output that I can easily query via JMES to find any status.

```yaml
    ## Build an array (fact) of only names of variable 'var_pcs_resources'
    - name: set_fact_pcs_resource_names
      ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        fact_pcs_resource_names: "{{ fact_pcs_resource_names | default([]) + [ {'name': item.name} ] }}"
        cacheable: yes
      loop: "{{ var_pcs_resources }}"
      run_once: True

    ## Build an array (fact) using 'fact_pcs_resource_name' as the variable
    - name: set_fact_pcs_resource_status
      ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        fact_pcs_resource_status: "{{ fact_pcs_resource_status | default([]) + [ {'name': item.name, 'type': type, 'state': state, 'target': target } ] }}"
        cacheable: yes
      loop: "{{ ansible_facts.fact_pcs_resource_names }}"
      vars:
        regex_expression: "{{ item.name }}\\s+\\((.*)\\):\\s+(\\S*)\\s+(\\S*)"
        type: "{{ reg_command_pcs_status.stdout | regex_search(regex_expression, '\\1') | first }}"
        state: "{{ reg_command_pcs_status.stdout | regex_search(regex_expression, '\\2') | first }}"
        target: "{{ reg_command_pcs_status.stdout | regex_search(regex_expression, '\\3') | first }}"
      run_once: True
```

This will produce the output of:

```
TASK [vcd_nfs_cluster : debug_vars] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Friday 09 April 2021  11:41:12 -0400 (0:00:02.215)       0:00:14.389 ********** 
ok: [testserver06.local.net] => {
    "ansible_facts.fact_pcs_resource_status": [
        {
            "name": "nfsclst02-lvm",
            "state": "Started",
            "target": "testserver07.local.net",
            "type": "ocf::heartbeat:LVM"
        },
        {
            "name": "lvm_transfer",
            "state": "Started",
            "target": "testserver07.local.net",
            "type": "ocf::heartbeat:Filesystem"
        },
        {
            "name": "nfs-daemon",
            "state": "Started",
            "target": "testserver07.local.net",
            "type": "ocf::heartbeat:nfsserver"
        },
        {
            "name": "nfs-transfer01_18",
            "state": "Started",
            "target": "testserver07.local.net",
            "type": "ocf::heartbeat:exportfs"
        },
        {
            "name": "nfs-transfer03_18",
            "state": "Started",
            "target": "testserver07.local.net",
            "type": "ocf::heartbeat:exportfs"
        },
        {
            "name": "nfs-transfer01_19",
            "state": "Started",
            "target": "testserver07.local.net",
            "type": "ocf::heartbeat:exportfs"
        },
        {
            "name": "nfs-transfer03_19",
            "state": "Started",
            "target": "testserver07.local.net",
            "type": "ocf::heartbeat:exportfs"
        },
        {
            "name": "nfs-transfer01_20",
            "state": "Started",
            "target": "testserver07.local.net",
            "type": "ocf::heartbeat:exportfs"
        },
        {
            "name": "nfs-transfer03_20",
            "state": "Started",
            "target": "testserver07.local.net",
            "type": "ocf::heartbeat:exportfs"
        },
        {
            "name": "nfs-transfer01_21",
            "state": "Started",
            "target": "testserver07.local.net",
            "type": "ocf::heartbeat:exportfs"
        },
        {
            "name": "nfs-transfer03_21",
            "state": "Started",
            "target": "testserver07.local.net",
            "type": "ocf::heartbeat:exportfs"
        },
        {
            "name": "nfs-transfer01_22",
            "state": "Started",
            "target": "testserver07.local.net",
            "type": "ocf::heartbeat:exportfs"
        },
        {
            "name": "nfs-transfer03_22",
            "state": "Started",
            "target": "testserver07.local.net",
            "type": "ocf::heartbeat:exportfs"
        },
        {
            "name": "nfs_vip",
            "state": "Started",
            "target": "testserver07.local.net",
            "type": "ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2"
        },
        {
            "name": "nfs-notify",
            "state": "Started",
            "target": "testserver07.local.net",
            "type": "ocf::heartbeat:nfsnotify"
        }
    ]
}
```